# Handling multiple Rest web services using Spring and Castor

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, spring-mvc, castor

Would anyone be able to advise me on the best way of handling access to multiple Rest web services using Springs `RestTemplate`?

I know that the `RestTemplate` object has a message converter reference (`MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`) which in turn has a reference to an `unmarshaller`.  In my case I am using the Spring Frameworks `CastorMarshaller` object with associated mapping file.

Normally I could have just added all my mappings to one Castor mapping file.  However in my case all the web services are of this format (block below) with the < rows ... /> holding different entities depending on the service called.

```
<data>
<output>
    <dataset>
        <row id="" .... />
        <row id="" .... />
        <row id="" .... />
        <row id="" .... />
        <row id="" .... />
    </dataset>
</output>
<nextUpdate><nextUpdate/> 
</data>
```

The `CastorMarshaller` is injected into the `MessageConverter` which itself is injected into the `RestTemplate` in the application context configuration file.

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller"/>
                <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller"/>
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                            <constructor-arg index="0" value="application"/>
                            <constructor-arg index="1" value="xml"/>
                        </bean>                     
                        <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                            <constructor-arg index="0" value="text"/>
                            <constructor-arg index="1" value="xml"/>
                        </bean>     
                    </list>
                </property>

            </bean>

        </list>
    </property>                 
</bean>

<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
    <property name="mappingLocation" value="classpath:oxm-mapping-worldweather.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Possible options that I have been thinking about:

1 Create multiple `RestTemplates` for each Rest service.

2 Create multiple `MessageConverters` for the different services and change the message converters on the template when accessing a different service.

3 Create multiple `CasterMarshaller` objects for the different services and update the message converter with the new `unmarshaller`

What is the best way to approach handling multiple services like this with the same root and sub elements?

Thanks in advance
Sman UK

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the issue.  Is the issue that you are only specifying one mapping file in the CasterMarshaller?  I don't know much about Castor, but just browsing their javadocs seems to indicate a way to include mutiple mapping files in it's context: createXMLContext(Resource[] mappingLocations, Class targetClass)

Comment: I am new to castor but the docs suggest you can use something like 
mapping.loadMapping(new InputSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
        "mapping1.xml"))); 
and call this multiple times for different mapping files

Answer (score 0):

If specifying multiple mapping files is the issue then below is the solution.

Use mappingLocations property instead of mappingLocation as given below,

```
<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:oxm-mapping-worldweather.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:sample-mapping.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```